# How to use same cookies in multiple request in python?

Tags: python, http, cookies, httprequest

I am using this code:

```
def req(url, postfields):
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support) 
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    return opener.open(url).read()
```

To make a simple http get request (using tor as proxy).

**Now I would like to know how to make multiple request using the same cookie.**

For example:

```
req('http://loginpage', 'postfields')
source = req('http://pageforloggedinonly', 0)
#do stuff with source
req('http://anotherpageforloggedinonly', 'StuffFromSource')
```

I know that my function req doesn't support POST (yet), but I have sent postfields using httplib so I guess I can figure that by myself, but I don't understand how to use cookies, I saw some examples but they are all one request only, I want to reuse the cookie from the first login request in the succeeding requests, or saving/using the cookie from a file (like curl does), that would make everything easier.

The code I posted I only to illustrate what I am trying to achieve, I think I will use httplib(2) for the final app.

**UPDATE:**

cookielib.LWPCOokieJar worked fine, here's a sample I did for testing:

```
import urllib2, cookielib, os

def request(url, postfields, cookie):
    urlopen = urllib2.urlopen
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    Request = urllib2.Request

    if os.path.isfile(cookie):
        cj.load(cookie)

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    txheaders =  {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'}

    req = Request(url, postfields, txheaders)
    handle = urlopen(req)
    cj.save(cookie)
    return handle.read()

print request('http://google.com', None, 'cookie.txt')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html) module is what you need to do this.  There's a nice [tutorial](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/cookielib.shtml) with some code samples.